# How to list all actions of all visitors segmented by a url parameter?

Tags: matomo

In my marketing campaigns I have links with param `?uid=123` or similar, signifying a user id. How do I look at the reports of all actions per-user (as categorized by the uid parameter)? Is this a custom dimension, or some other technique? Is there a common way to do this, using utm tags?